# How to use Access database with query as pivot table in Excel

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, pivot-table

I want to use Access database with query for pivot table in Excel.

How do I do that?

Comment: What's your XL version ? It's very different in 2007 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Excel and select Data->Pivot Table....->External data source->Get Data.
Then select Microsoft Access MDB and find your MDB file. Select the
appropriate tables and/or queries and fields.

Comment: yup i was able to go through the wizard. .but the thing is it gave me this error:

"The Query Wizrd can not continue because it can not join the tables in your query. You must join the tables manually in Microsoft Query by dragging the fileds to join between the tables."

My Access Database has a table with the raw data and i have a separate query for the specific values that is equivalent to one of the columns in my main table. 

So basically i want to know on how to make such connection when use in the pivot...